# What's the meaning of にもin その話は前にも聞いたよ。?

Tags: translation, particles, particle-に, particle-も

> その話は前にも聞いたよ

is translated as

> "I heard that story before"

I assume that the subject is implicit, その話 "that story" is the topic, 前 is "before" and 聞いた is the past of hear. What about にも? Why is 前 marked with these particles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> その話は前に**も**聞いたよ。

The も means "too; also; as well". 前にも means "(something happened) before, *too* (as well as now)". So you'd say 前にも when something that happened before is happening again now. Compare:

> - その話は前**にも**聞いたよ。 I heard that before, too. / This is not the first time you've told me the story. / This is the second time you're telling me that.
> - その話は前**に**聞いたよ。 I heard that before. / I know the story.

Another example:

> - その公園には前**にも**行ったことがあるよ。 I went to that park before, too. / This is the second time for me to go to that park.
> - その公園には前**に**行ったことがあるよ。 I've been to that park.

Answer (score 7):

に in 前に can serve as a time marker (as in `その時に`) which would complete the "before" translation.

も and the ending よ give an additional sense of "already," perhaps multiple times before. The combined にも can express annoyance.

> 前にもあった：It has happened before.
>
> 前にも言ったけど: I've (already) said it before, but...